# Munin - graph not visible when host down

Tags: debian, munin

This night, a server of my farm has failed

But, in my munin server, i have lost graph of the host which failed during the night. After reboot host (this morning), and few minutes later, this host is again in my Munin interface

Is this normal behavior?

Is it possible to change this behavior? I'd like to remain in the host interface Munin, even if it is bug.

THanks you,

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behaviour on my munin setup.

I believe this is a bug http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/758 and has been addressed but according to the latest comment, it's not completely solved.

Comment: I am seeing this too on 1.4.5, can someone confirm that this still happens on newer versions as last comment on bug report says?

Comment: on Debian Wheezy (munin 2.0) this does not happen :)